# Google Maps API v3... non-mobile?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a Google Maps widget for my website but all of the examples are for full-screen mobile devices. The tutorials work when I copy paste them exactly as shown but they don't seem to work when I want them to only occupy a portion of the page.

From what I've read, the v3 is the best API yet (for what I need) because of its speed and compatibility with mobile devices. I plan to make a widget very similar to the [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html) example from the demo gallery but I can't get it working.

Is this a common issue? I know I'm being vague but I would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: The more specific you are, the more we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One minute after I post this question, I find the problem...

The examples have the map_canvas div set to width:100%;height:100% which I have changed as follows:

Hope this helps somebody after me...

Comment: You never added the code to show how you fixed it :(